# Benchmarking with QtCreator, how to set iterations?

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, testing, qt-creator

I'm following https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest-overview.html and I created a benchmark test which I can run within QtCreator.

```
CONFIG+=sdk_no_version_check
QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 12.0

QT += testlib

HEADERS += \
    ../aclass/aclass.h \

SOURCES += \
    ../aclass/aclass.cpp \
    benchaclass.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += ../aclass
```

```
#include "aclass.h"

#include <QObject>
#include <QTest>

class BenchAClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private slots:

    void doWork()
    {
        AClass a;
        QVERIFY(a.doWork() == 1);

        QBENCHMARK{
            a.doWork();
        }
    }

};

QTEST_MAIN(BenchAClass)

#include "benchaclass.moc"
```

Where I got a message saying maximum amount of iterations exceeded.

And I see there is the command line option:

> -iterations n
> Sets the number of accumulation iterations.

Is there a way to use that option from within QtCreator?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the -iterations command-line option with Qt Creator by modifying the run configuration for your test. Here are the steps to do so:

1. List item Select your test project from the list of projects.
2. In the "Run" section, click the "Details" button to open the run
   configuration editor.
3. In the "Command line arguments" field, enter -iterations n, where n
   is the number of iterations you want to run. For example, to run 100
   iterations, you would enter -iterations 100.
4. Click "Apply" to save your changes.

Now when you run your benchmark test from within Qt Creator, it will use the specified number of iterations. You should no longer see the "maximum amount of iterations exceeded" message.